# Toilet leaking, possibly related to loose screws?

Tags: leak, toilet

Pools of water have started to appear next to the base of my toilet. There are two screws near the base of the toilet. One of them is totally loose (see photo) - it just spins and I can waggle it around and it doesn't seem like there's anything vaguely near for it to screw into. I'm not sure what it is meant to screw into. Other information:

- It might not be the loose screws that cause the water to pool - the cistern gets a lot of condensation  - perhaps the water is then dripping off there to the floor. I've tried to confirm isn't not this by using a towel to 'catch' the condensation and water still appeared on the floor, but it's not a perfect test.
- When I flush the toilet, water doesn't come out of the screw holes or anywhere else.
- The toilet does not rock when pushed.
- I can't figure out what the toilet brand is so can't look up a manual etc. On the inside of the cistern lid it says "L34" but have not been able to use that to find the brand.

[image: screw out]

Comment: I can't tell what I'm looking at in that fuzzy photo. Is that a _horizontal_ bolt? In any case, the condensation seems like the mostly likely issue if the base doesn't rock at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify that the condensation is or isn't the cause of the water pooling at the toilet base, first. Placing a paper sheet under the tank will show if the water is dripping.

Also check that the supply hose at both ends are not leaking. Make sure the vale is seat tightly by tightening the nut at the bottom (outside) of the tank.

Also check that the tank is secure to the bowl. Tighten the (2) nuts on the underside of the tank.

I found using a flashlight helps locate any leaks around the bowl and tank. If none are found chances are the leak is due to the wax ring not sealing and you'll need to pull the toilet and install a new ring.

You may want to remove the toilet anyway to re-attach the brass bolt that has come loose. The toilet flange may have broken where the bolt is placed.

Comment: Careful with tightening the supply hose, the toilet side is usually plastic. The seal between that plastic part and the toilet tank is another possible source of leak.